# Normalizing JSON parameter between 4 types

Tags: c#, json.net

I have 4 possible outcomes for one parameter that I would like to normalize to a `List<ResponseModel>`

Input1:

```
{
    "err": 0,
    "misc": "stringGoesHere",
    "otherMisc": "stringGoesHere",
    "responseModel": [
        "responseModel1" : {
            //Stuff I want
        },
        "responseModel2" : {
            //Stuff I want
        }
    ]
}
```

input2:

```
{
    "err": 0,
    "misc": "stringGoesHere",
    "otherMisc": "stringGoesHere",
    "responseModel": [
        "oldResponseModel1" : {
            //Stuff I want
        },
        "oldResponseModel2" : {
            //Stuff I want
        }
    ]
}
```

input3:

```
{
    "err": 0,
    "misc": "stringGoesHere",
    "otherMisc": "stringGoesHere",
    "responseModel":  {
            //Stuff I want
    }
}
```

I have tried deserializing with Json.net JsonConverter and, I can get the first input2 to work, but trying to use SelectAll ends in a StackOverflow exception.

My conversion override looks something like this:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    // object only
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        T instance = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(T));
        result = new List<T>() { instance };
    }
    // list of objects
    else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
    {
        try
        {
            List<T> stillArray = serializer.Deserialize<List<T>>(reader).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, stillArray ends in a StackOverflow exception. What am I missing with this conversion?

Comment: where are you getting the StackOverflow exception? I don't see a SelectAll line.

Comment: @mmcrae the List<T> stillArray conversion restarts the ReadJson when I would like to check if it is a List<List<T>>.